# How to redirect amazon images from http to https using htaccess

Tags: image, .htaccess, redirect, amazon-s3

My client is using amazon to store images for his magento store.
The problem is that in checkout onepage browser says that ssl is not secure becouse some resources are loaded via http.

How i can load all the images that contains this url: http://[username].s3.amazonaws.com/...etc via https, like: http**s**://[username].s3.amazonaws.com/...etc

Here is what i tried and i think i'm close but i'm redirect in browser

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^https://absolutetoner.s3.amazonaws.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://absolutetoner.s3.amazonaws.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It should be simple but i'm stuck.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Any ideea if this is posible and how i can do that? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if your `s3` Amazon account has Apache and they allow `mod_rewrite` rules. Can you check with them?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not simple, and, in fact, it's not possible.  You need to fix the links in the web page to use https.

It's not possible for one of several reasons.  Which reason applies will depend on why you think this would work.

If you expect these rules to rewrite the html of the pages, that's not what they do.  They rewrite incoming requests, which isn't helpful, because...

The web server never sees these requests.  Putting these rules in an `.htaccess` file on the web server serves no purpose, because these requests will never reach the web server.  Their hostname points them to S3, and that's where the requests from the browser will go.  The web server will never see these requests, so it can't redirect them...

Even if the requests could reach the web server, that doesn't help with the security warning, because the web page still has *links to insecure content*.  Even if a redirect from http to https did happen, information is being sent in the clear during the initial insecure request, so an https redirection does not address the underlying problem...

Or, if you're putting the `.htaccess` file on S3 itself, then of course it will have no effect, because S3 does not support `.htaccess`.

In this day and age, there's really no good reason not to use SSL by default for everything... but the alternative to that, if for some reason you don't want to or "can't," is to use `//` in the links instead of `http://`.  This causes the links to be fetched with the same scheme (http or https) as the one used to load the main page.  Example:

```
<img src="//example.s3.amazonaws.com/img.jpg">
```